# Sync a specific set of files from Amazon S3 to Dropbox or Amazon Drive

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, dropbox, amazon-drive

I have an Amazon S3 bucket with tons of images. A subset of these images need to be synced to a local machine for image analysis (AI) purposes. This has to be done regularly and ideally with a list of file names as input. Not all images need to be synced.

There are ways to synchronise S3 with either Dropbox/Amazon Drive or other storage services, but none of them appear to have the option to provide a list of files that need to be synced.

How can this be implemented?

Comment: If i use `aws cli` I can use the include/exclude feature for this https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3/index.html#use-of-exclude-and-include-filters

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first thing that springs to mind when talking about syncing and s3 is using the [aws s3 sync](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3/sync.html) cli command. This will allow you to sync specific origin destination folders as well as afford you the ability to use **--include**, **--exclude** if you want to list specific files. The commands also allow for the use of wildcards [*] if you have specific naming conventions you can use to identify the files.

You can also repeatedly call the --exclude command for multiple files, so depending on your OS you could either list all files or create a [find](https://ss64.com/bash/find.html) script that identifies the files and singles them out.

Additionally you are able to do **--delete** which will remove any files in the destination path that are not in the origin.

Comment: I see that I can use multiple --includes. I could programmatically generate a command with thousands of --includes, would that work, or is there a limit?

Comment: I don't think there's a hard limit on the number of includes, however you would be better off generating a unique metadata tag on your files that you can use to identify which files you would copy across. The answer is better suited to when you have a folder structure or consistent naming convention you can leverage.

Comment: That would be a feasible solution, but I don't see an option in --include to select by tag, only by filename. Do you have a suggestion?

Comment: Correct, you will need to get a bit crafty here. Either a custom lambda which can call on a library like boto3 or a combination of cli commands. You will need to list all the items, then retrieve the [link] (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3api/get-object-tagging.html) tag, afterwards pass that list to a copy function or cli command. Again i would say the easiest solution is to split by directory or naming convention. Alternatively, and is quite a 'sloppy solution', restrict IAM permissions to only copy files with that tag, which would prevent you copying the non tagged files

Comment: Thanks for your help! I actually came up with an alternative solution. The specs have changed and I don't need to sync to a cloud service anymore; a simple `aws s3 cp` is good enough for this use case. I just generate a .bat file with all `aws s3 cp` commands and run it on the local machine.

Comment: Sounds like a good outcome, and no worries glad you got a solution that works for you .

Answer (score 0):

> As much as I would like to answer but I felt it would be good to
>   comment with one's thoughts initially if they are in line with the OP!
>
> But I see the comments are being used to provide an answer to gain
>   points :)
>
> I would like to submit my official answer!

**Ans:**

If I get this correctly I would use `aws cli` wth filters of include and exclude.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3/index.html#use-of-exclude-and-include-filters